# Restricting users to their home-directory in FTP (ftpd)

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

I have installed ftpd on my Debian client and I'm trying to setup some restrictions but I'm not sure which way to go.

I have 3 users:

- Bob
- Alice
- Max

One group called:

- Clients

And a new partition called:

- /dump

Bob and Alice are in the Clients group. Not Max.

Here's my problem: I would want to restrict the users to their home-directory, I don't want Alice to have access to Bobs or Max directory and vice versa. I also want the users in the Clients group (Bob and Alice) to have access to the new /dump partition, Max should not have access.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vsftpd, try this:

Open vsftpd configuration file – /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Make sure following line exists (and uncommented):

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Save and close the file. Restart vsftpd.

```
# /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I tried with filezilla and logged in as Bob but I can still access both Alices and Max directory for some reason.